# Wrapping c++ class in cython when header defines the class *and* a pointer class

Tags: c++, pointers, cython

I'm writing a cython interface to a c++ library. This library defines a bunch of classes as well as pointer class for each class. Then, you request a class instance returned as a pointer type that you can you can.

### E.g. for the `System` class the library has a base pointer class:

```cpp
template <class T, class B = T> class BasePtr
    {
      public:
        //! Default constructor.
        BasePtr(void) throw();

        virtual ~BasePtr(void);

        //! Dereferencing
        virtual operator T*(void)const;

        //! Dereferencing
        virtual T* operator->(void)const;
    }
...
```

and a `SystemPtr` for the `System` class:

```cpp
class SystemPtr : public BasePtr<ISystem>
    {
      public:
        //! Default constructor
        SystemPtr(){};

        //! Virtual destructor
        virtual ~SystemPtr(void){};
    };
```

and then the actual `System` class:

```cpp
class System : public ISystem
    {
      public:
        /**
         * @return A const ref to a system object.
         */
        static SystemPtr GetInstance();

        /**
         * Default destructor.
         */
        virtual ~System();

        virtual void ReleaseInstance();
    }
```

### in my Cython code I have something like:

```
cdef extern from "System.h" nogil:
    cppclass SystemPtr:
        SystemPtr() except +

    cdef cppclass System:
        @staticmethod
        SystemPtr GetInstance() except +
        void ReleaseInstance() except +
```

### and then:

```
cdef SystemPtr system = System.GetInstance()
system.ReleaseInstance()
```

This gives the following error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

system.ReleaseInstance()
^
------------------------------------------------------------

rotpy\system.pyx:114:28: Object of type 'SystemPtr' has no attribute 'ReleaseInstance'
```

So I tried instead:

```
cdef System *system = System.GetInstance()
```

but then I get:

```
Cannot assign type 'SystemPtr' to 'System *'
```

Finally I tried:

```
cdef System *system = <System *>System.GetInstance()
```

but then I get

```
system.cpp(1403): error C2440: 'type cast': cannot convert from 'SystemPtr' to 'System *'
system.cpp(1403): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

and at this point I'm not sure what to do as I'm not very familiar with c++ so don't feel comfortable messing with class pointers arbitrarily.

Comment: In C++, you would call system-> ReleaseInstance(). SystemPtr doesn't have the method ReleaseInstance() but it has an operator (->) to access to the pointer that has the method. I am not very familiar with cython syntax. But if your dereference was virtual T* get() const; you python would be: cdef SystemPtr system = System.GetInstance()
system.get().ReleaseInstance()

Comment: Beautiful, I didn't realize that there's a `get()` function. I added `System * get() const` based on the header's `virtual T* get() const` and that allowed me to use `get` as you described! If you write it as an answer I'll accept it unless someone comes up a more native way of doing it in cython without get!

Comment: I don't think there's a more native way. There's probably other options (you might be able to use `dereference` instead for example) but it's a little clunky whatever you do